# get key value pairs out from the string javascript

Tags: javascript

If my string looks like this

```
"<First key="ab" value="qwerty"/>
<First key="cd" value="asdfg"/>
<First key="ef" value="zxcvb"/>"
```

and I want to get data out in the format

ab:"qwerty"
cd:"asdfg"
ef:"zxcvb"

How should I write the JS ?

Comment: Double quotes inside double quotes need to be escaped (e.g. `"Hello \"sir\"."`

Comment: This feels like a silly solution and needs jQuery but i'll share in case it helps https://jsfiddle.net/nv33h22t/2/

Comment: Where did this string come from? Is your desired output a string of the format you mention, or a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 3):

It would be useful to see the code you've attempted, but here's a way you could achieve it:

Use a regex to pick out the relevant parts of the string.

```
var regex = /key="([a-zA-Z]+)" value="([0-9a-zA-Z\-\.]+)"/;
```

Function to remove empty elements.

```
var notEmpty = function (el) { return el !== ''; };
```

`split` the string into an array on the carriage return and use `reduce` to build the new object by applying the regex to each array element.

```
var out = str.split('\n').filter(notEmpty).reduce(function(p, c) {
  var match = c.match(regex);
  p[match[1]] = match[2];
  return p;
}, {});
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  "ab": "qwerty",
  "cd": "asdfg",
  "ef": "zxcvb"
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hoemof0n/7/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hoemof0n/3/
I tried this solution with my string and it gives me an error, Do you know why? I am new to JS.

Comment: You need to provide more information on your string. Update the fiddle with your input and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Regarding the string, I have a text area where the user pastes a similar string. Since I am using angular js, I got the value of the string using: var str= $element. find('#box').val()

Comment: Can you post the link to the updated fiddle, please.

Comment: The regex works now https://jsfiddle.net/hoemof0n/7/ but I did have to run "tidy up" to reformat the HTML which you might have to do manually, or run a beautifier on it after someone's pasted in the code. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make your question more clear(What result data type would you like to get?), or try these functions:

```
var string = '<First key="ab" value="qwerty"/><First key="cd" value="asdfg"/><First key="ef" value="zxcvb"/>'

var ParseMyString1 = function(str){
var arr = str.split(/[</>]+/); //" 
//console.log(arr);
var result = [];

for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var subStr=arr[i];
    if (subStr.length!==0) {
        var subArr = subStr.split(/[\s"=]+/);    //" 
        //console.log(subArr);
        var currObj = {};            
        var currKey = "";
        var currVal = "";
        for (var j =0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if (subArr[j]=="key"){
                currKey = subArr[++j];                                                            
            }else if (subArr[j]=="value"){
                currVal = subArr[++j];                                                            
            }
        };
        currObj[currKey] = currVal;
        result.push(currObj);
    };
};
console.log("ParseMyString1:");
console.log(result);
};

var ParseMyString2 = function(str){
var arr = str.split(/[</>]+/); //" 
//console.log(arr);
var resultObj = {};
for (var i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var subStr=arr[i];
    if (subStr.length!==0) {
        var subArr = subStr.split(/[\s"=]+/);    //" 
        //console.log(subArr);

        var currKey = "";
        var currVal = "";
        for (var j =0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if (subArr[j]=="key"){
                currKey = subArr[++j];                                                            
            }else if (subArr[j]=="value"){
                currVal = subArr[++j];                                                            
            }
        };
        resultObj[currKey] = currVal;

    };
};
console.log("ParseMyString2:");
console.log(resultObj);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  ParseMyString1(string);
  ParseMyString2(string);
});
```

These functions return results as below (array of objects):

```
ParseMyString1:
[{ab:"qwerty"},{cd:"asdfg"},{ef:"zxcvb"}]
ParseMyString2:
{ab:"qwerty",cd:"asdfg",ef:"zxcvb"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your string is not valid (double quotes within double quotes). You'd either need to escape the inner quotes with `\"` or just replace the inner quotes with single quotes.

But, assuming that your data was always going to be in the format you show, this simple code will extract the data the way you want:

```js
var data = "<First key='ab' value='qwerty'/><First key='cd' value='asdfg'/><First key='ef' value='zxcvb'/>";
data = data.replace(/<First /g, " ").replace(/\/>/g, "").replace(/key=/g, "").replace(/value=/g, "").trim();

var ary = data.split(" ");

var iteration = "";
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i+=2){
  
  iteration = ary[i].replace(/'/g, "") + ":" + ary[i+1].replace(/'/g, "\"");
  alert(iteration); 
  result += " " + iteration;
}

alert("Final result: " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a kind of XML. The best way is to treat it as such. We will parse it as XML, but to do so, we need to first wrap it in a root element:

```
var str = "<Root>" + input + "</Root>"
```

We parse it with

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dom = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
```

Get the document element (`Root`):

```
var docelt = dom.documentElement;
```

Now we can loop over its children and build our result, using standard DOM access interfaces like `getAttribute`:

```
var result = {};
var children = docelt.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var child = children[i];
  result[child.getAttribute('key')] = child.getAttribute('value');
}

> result
< Object {ab: "qwerty", cd: "asdfg", ef: "zxcvb"}
```

You can replace the above looping logic with `reduce` or something else as you prefer.

This approach has the advantage that it takes advantage of the built-in parser, so we don't end up making assumptions about the syntax of XML. For instance, the regexp suggested in another answer would fail if the attributes had spaces before or after the equal sign. It would fail if the values contained Unicode characters. It would fail in odd ways if the XML was malformed. And so on.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to extract more than one value for a key. I don't want to concatenate them together as a string. 
example <item key ="a" value1="b" value2="c"/>
Output: a: b, c